# Call R library at beginning of file or before use?

Tags: r, libraries

I have been putting all my library calls at the top of my a main R file.  But after creating more files, making code more abstract, I'm wondering if I'm doing things wrong.  I see benefits both ways:

TOP of file - you get to see everything that is used at once, and as long as you call these once, they are in the environment and you only need call them once

BEFORE USE - code (esp functions and sourced files) are more self-contained, but you may end up calling a library more than once (not sure if that's a problem).

Which is the correct way to call R libraries:  at the beginning of a script/file or before use?

Comment: Thank goodness got some answers in before the 'canonical question'-Nazis got here ;).  Most of your options are below, including the facts, references, to help you make your decision. It's good to know about options ;)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is an 'official' way to do this, but the [Google R style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml) suggests the following (emphasis mine):

> General Layout and Ordering
>
> If everyone uses the same general ordering, we'll be able to read and understand each other's scripts faster and more easily.
>
> Copyright statement comment
>
> Author comment
> File description comment, including purpose of program, inputs, and outputs
>
> **source() and library() statements**
>
> Function definitions
>
> Executed statements, if applicable (e.g., print, plot)

This of course, means that library calls should be closer to the top (as in your first option). I guess the main thing is *consistency*, as Wickham states in [his style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html), which doesn't explicitly mentions script structures, but mentions a series of pros to being consistent if your code has many readers.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to depend on how you organize your R code, but in general I like to put all my library calls at the top. If you like to 'fire and forget', that is, run your whole file at once, then you want to put library calls at the top, that way you get your errors earlier rather than later.  If you run certain chunks at a time, then you might want to only have the library calls before each chunk (but in that case it might make sense to move each chunk to a different file).  As to your question about performance, unless you are running `library` in a tight loop or something, it isn't going to significantly effect on performance.

Answer (score 4):

I think putting library calls at the top of your code is preferred.

1. If a library is needed for the script, but isn't installed, then the code will fail early rather than potentially executing a long time before failing.
2. This also provides an advantage where functions are consistently masked (or not) from the global environment (or other environments). For example if you load a library or source a script that has the same name as a function in "base" R (e.g. loading `dplyr` masks `filter` and `lag` from `stats`) then you will be notified of this at the beginning of the execution rather than somewhere in the middle (where I think it is more likely to be missed). If a function is masked you can call it by using `package_name::function_name`.

Calling a library multiple times isn't a problem because (*I think*) R checks to see whether the library is already in the list of loaded namespaces. I think this is true because doing `library(dplyr)` followed by `library(stats)` doesn't reorder the results of `search()`.

Comment: So say you create a file of functions that you source from different scripts because you wnat to keep the functions abstract so you can use them in different documents and obey the DRY principle.  Would you create a 'meta-file' for each use of these functions which calls the necessary libraries?  Having all the libraries at the header is great when you aren't reusing code.  As soon as you start reusing, it seems like problems arise.  If your library calls are IN the functions, there wouldn't be this problem.

Comment: When I write functions that I want to reuse across projects I put them in a package. When I have functions that are specific to a project I might put them in a separate file that is sourced after I have loaded the libraries I'm going to use. In general library calls inside of a function aren't terribly different than outside of the function and if you put all of your functions at the top (with your library calls) then I think it just makes sense to put all of your library calls together.

Comment: I can see all calls at the top of a function.R file. That makes sense, because you'll source the file from any number of places and those functions will need those libraries.  But as soon as you need to source these functions from a different place (you start a new project), you are creating a wrapper/script just to load libraries that these functions need and then digging into the files or running the script till it barks about missing some library just to put in the wrapper/script. I think libraries together at the top of the individual file (not main file) seems like the way to go.

Comment: It also looks like according to ?library: " Both functions check and update the list of currently loaded packages and do not reload a package which is already loaded." Therefore there really isn't much harm to having multiple calls to the same library.

Comment: Yeah I'm not arguing against putting library calls at the top of the scripts you're sourcing, I'm saying I don't do it. I put my functions into a package if they are going to be used across projects or I put them in their own chunk in my RMarkdown document (immediately after I load my libraries).

Comment: Well maybe a better way is to put them at the top of the file you're sourcing. That way even if you don't create a package you can source it, and when you do, it will still work.  And you can use the function in different projects.  Of course, the function has to really be portable/useful enough to put it in it's own file (though I guess you could do it for code organization purposes).